# Is it normal to receive llvm toolchain updates every single day?

Tags: upgrade, updates, clang

I sudo aptitude upgrade all my packages every day and up until a few weeks ago, I've never had any software (including llvm/clang) that requested upgrades every single day but that is what has started happening with my llvm toolchain for a couple weeks now.

> The following packages will be upgraded:
> clang-16
> libclang-common-16-dev libclang-cpp16 libclang1-16 libllvm16 lld-16
> llvm-16    llvm-16-dev llvm-16-linker-tools llvm-16-runtime
> llvm-16-tools

Every single day.

So I am wondering if this is normal or if perhaps something got broken at some point. I'm on 22.04 LTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The latest release of LLVM](https://releases.llvm.org/#download) is [15.0.6 from November, 29<sup>th</sup> (11 days ago)](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-15.0.6). LLVM 16 is under development and has not been released yet, there is not even a pre-release.

[The release branch for even-numbered releases is always created on the fourth Tuesday of January](https://llvm.org/docs/HowToReleaseLLVM.html), release-candidates are released 3 days, 2 weeks, and 4 weeks after, and the .0 release after 6 weeks. So, LLVM 16 will not be released until March, 7<sup>th</sup> at the earliest, three months from now.

The release that is currently (December, 10<sup>th</sup>) carried by the latest official release of Ubuntu, 22.10 "Kinetic Kudu" is [15.0.2-1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=llvm&searchon=names). Even the next release, Ubuntu 23.04 "Lunar Lobster" doesn't have LLVM 16 yet (it has 15.0.6-3), which makes sense since LLVM 16 is not released.

So, wherever you installed this from, it was not from Ubuntu. And since LLVM 16 has not entered the release phase yet, [the LLVM project itself only publishes nightly snapshots](https://apt.llvm.org/#install_dev).

Since you installed nightly snapshots, it should be obvious that they are updated nightly. That's why they are called "nightly".